# Why dynamic programming is required for this?

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming, sequences

The problem statement can be found [here.](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-common-substring/) It says there that the DP solution will take O(m*n) time. But why do we need DP in there? I've written the following solution and not sure if DP is required at all.

```
    String str1,str2;
    str1 = "OldSite:GeeksforGeeks.org";
    str2 = "NewSite:GeeksQuiz.com";

    int i,j,k;
    int count,currentMax =0;
    for(i = 0; i < str1.length();i++){
        count = 0;
        k = i;
        for(j = 0; j < str2.length() && k < str1.length();j++){
            if(str1.charAt(k) == str2.charAt(j)){
                count++;
                k++;
            }
            else if(count > currentMax)
                    currentMax = count;
            continue;
        }
        if(count > currentMax)
            currentMax = count;
    }

    System.out.println(currentMax);
```

Even my solution takes O(m*n) but I don't seem to be doing it the DP way.

What I've done is that check for each character in string1, what is the max length available in string 2.

Basically I think this is the brute force method.

Anything wrong with my solution?

**EDIT** As Mentioned in the comments section.

making changes to produce correct result changing the inner for loop as

```
for(j = 0; j < str2.length() && k < str1.length();j++){
            if(str1.charAt(k) == str2.charAt(j)){
                count++;
                k++;
            }
            else if(count > currentMax){
                    currentMax = count;
                    count = 0;
                                            k=i;
            }
            else{
                count = 0;
                                    k=i;
                            }
            continue;
}
```

**EDIT 2** For the comments.

```
for(j = 0; j < str2.length() && k < str1.length();j++){
            if(str1.charAt(k) == str2.charAt(j)){
                count++;
                k++;
            }
            else if(count > currentMax){
                    currentMax = count;
                    count = 0;
                    k=i;
                    if(str1.charAt(k) == str2.charAt(j)){
                        count++;
                        k++;
                    }
            }
            else{
                count = 0;
                k=i;
                if(str1.charAt(k) == str2.charAt(j)){
                    count++;
                    k++;
                }
            }
            continue;
        }
```

Comment: The link you post says the problem can be solved using a suffix tree, so DP isn't needed.

Answer (score 5):

I think you code for longest common substring is not working try input :-

```
str1 = "swring";
str2 = "skwkring";
```

The Longest common substring here is "ring" which is 4 characters but your code gives "6" answer. Here i think your code is just counting the common characters in the strings which is "swring" so result is 6.

You cannot solve this using brute force in **O(n*m)** though it seems obvious so DP is used.

**Edit :-**

Your edited solutions covers more problems but still is not perfect for centrally positioned strings due to same reasons that it is **greedy** unlike **DP**

**check :-**

```
str1 = "sbsringada";
str2 = "cdssringasd";
```

The correct ans is `6` that is `"sringa"` but the code outputs `5`. The reason being it gets **greedy** at "s" before `"sringa"` in str2.

**Edit:-**

This will go on for ever where you will give a code i will give you where it doesnt work unless you dont find the actual brute algorithm or prove that your code is correct mathematically.

As you have not proved it , i will give you the actual brute force code which i had once written for the same problem . It is very simple and intuitive to understand but very inefficient.

**Pseudo code :-**

```
int max = 0;

for(int i=0;i<str1.length,i++) {

 for(int j=0;j<str2.length;j++) {
    int k = 0;  
    for(;j+k<str2.length && i+k < str1.length ;k++) {
        if(str1[i+k]!=str[j+k]) 
           break;
    }

    if(k>max)
        max = k;
 }


}

print(max);
```

The time complexity this code is `O(m*n*min(m,n))`

For further progress you need to prove that your code does similar to this one like in case of DP its proven by induction.

Comment: But you can actually see intuitively that O(m*n) using the above method is possible (even though I might've screwed up some assignments).
If I take one character at a time from string 1, and see what is the max length of substring in string 2, and I take the maximum for all the characters in String 1. Now, complexity to check the max substring for a character in string 1 would be size of string 2. Hence overall for m characters in string one, it will be m*size of string 2.

Comment: I think you are confusing the problem with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem.

Comment: @GeoAoe not i am not see my example